# Wordpress does not save Custom Field

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I am working with several Custom Fields which are "allocated" to Custom Post Types. For some odd reason one Custom Field needs to be created over and over again. I cannot seem to find a solution that this specific Custom Field is saved onto my Wordpress Database for future use.

The Custom Field is called "video_url". Even if I rename it so "youtubelink" or whatsoever Wordpress does not save it. Any other newly created Custom Fields are saved by Wordpress but not that one that must hold the Youtube Link.

Any ideas? Is there something to "force" WP to keep that Custom Field?

NB: I am not using any Plugins to create Custom Fields.

Comment: Are you saving the custom field with php ? Can you provide us your code ?

Comment: Here's how I call the results for the specific Custom Post Type

''<?php if (!((get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_url', TRUE))=='')) {
                                    echo wp_oembed_get( get_post_meta($post->ID, "video_url", true) );
                                    }?>''

I basically want to display the embedded Youtube video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by increasing the Post Meta in my functions.php

Looks like Wordpress has a postmeta limit @ 30. With the function below you can increase it to higher values.

Works like a boss

```
/* Increase Postmeta Limit.*/

add_filter( 'postmeta_form_limit', function( $limit ) {
    return 100;
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use a php function to update or execute this sql in phpmyadmin

```
update `<your_prefix>_postmeta` pm set pm.meta_key = 'youtubelink' where  pm.meta_key = 'video_url'
```

If you use $wpdb you can add this code to function.php in your theme

```
global $wpdb;
 echo $sql = "update `{$wpdb->prefix}postmeta` pm set pm.meta_key = 'youtubelink' where  pm.meta_key = 'video_url'";
$wpdb->query($sql);
exit;
```

i added exit to make sure this code is executed. You reload page to run this script and then comment them to check. If nothing updated you use this code

```
global $wpdb,$prefix;
     echo $sql = "update `{$prefix}postmeta` pm set pm.meta_key = 'youtubelink' where  pm.meta_key = 'video_url'";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
    exit;
```

this is code used in old wordpress version. You reload page to run script, comment code to check again...

Comment: You need run this script in phpMyadmin or any where in function.php file. You can run it one time

Comment: so I just paste this one here into my functions.php? update `<your_prefix>_postmeta` pm set pm.meta_key = 'youtubelink' where  pm.meta_key = 'video_url'

Comment: No you must use it with $wpdb

Comment: sorry my skills in this regard are very limited. But basically like this

function someFunction() {
 
global $wpdb; update <your_prefix>_postmeta pm set pm.meta_key = 'youtubelink' where pm.meta_key = 'video_url' 
 
}

and then afterwards I can delete it out of the functions.php again?

Comment: Inserting this code into my function.php global $wpdb;
 echo $sql = "update `{$wpdb->prefix}postmeta` pm set pm.meta_key = 'youtubelink' where  pm.meta_key = 'video_url'";
$wpdb->query($sql);
exit;

Just displays the following onload of the website
update `wp_postmeta` pm set pm.meta_key = 'youtubelink' where pm.meta_key = 'video_url'

Comment: Update: adding new custom fields as meta still don't work

Comment: If you don't have many experience with custom field in wordpress, you had better use toolset plugin (https://wp-types.com/home/toolset-components/)